# Tomcat native library benefits

Tags: performance, web-applications, tomcat, native

Can anyone advise on the main benefits of installing the Tomcat native library?

I am running a standard installation of Tomcat to serve a moderately complex intranet based web app using Ext Js on the front end so lots of javascript and AJAX over the network and VPN from various locations.

Is it even worth installing this library for the comparatively small amount of requests it will be getting.

The app can be very slow at times and I'm looking to boost performance. I am already refactoring Java code based on profile data but as the problem seems to be more generalised I am also looking at the app server configuration and I can't seem to find any detail on whether this library would actually benefit me in this scenario.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are speaking about [Tomcat APR](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/apr.html). I personally don't believe that by simply switching the connector from non-native to native will automagically solve your performance problems.

Unless you have exercised all code inefficiencies (it seems that you are doing this already with the help of profiler) and solved them, it is probably not worth it.

I would envisage that APR helps in cases where most of requests are static and delivering static content becomes a bottleneck. To achieve this, you probably need to be delivering millions pages per day and having thread pool going through the roof (which I assume is not likely for your intranet).

Comment: This is kind of what I suspected, as what little information that I could find on the Apache site only seemed to relate to static content.

Answer (score 0):

Some of tomcat apr is not found in ubuntu repositories as they are no longer supported.

Please make sure these configurations are correct:

1. In eclipse under windows->preferences->servers-> runtime environment,
   choose the server where your project is deployed. Select the option installed jre and choose the java version you have installed or one you prefer.
2. Under project properties -> runtime environment select the server and press apply.
3. Under build path double click on jre library and choose the java version you have installed.

Native libraries are required when there is a mismatch between the code in the project in the jre version or the tomacat version.

Make sure that in your build and code, both are for the latest version of servlet that tomcat supports and jre is at its latest version that tomcat supports.

For example, if tomcat v8.5 supports java version 7 or above, you should have java version latest above 7 and tomcat v8.5 supports servlet version 3.1 so in your build set up. Make sure to use a container that uses servlet 3.1.